# How Could I use delegate successfully? Button doesn't work with delegates

Tags: swift, authentication, delegates

I'm new to swift.
I use delegate to login successfully.
but When I clicked login button, I can see only progress bar works.
How could I make button works and go to next page?
If I use in the loginButtonTapped button below. It works. but delegate doesn't work at all.

```
Presentermanager.shared.show(vc: .mainTabBarController)
```

Please help me out.

This is my source codes.

**LoadingViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

protocol LoginDelegate: class {
    func showMainTabBarController()
}

class LoadingViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let isUserLoggedIn =  false
    
    weak var delegate: LoginDelegate?
 
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        delay(durationInSeconds: 2.0) {
            self.showInitialView()
        }
    }
  
    private func showInitialView() {
        
        // if user is logged in => main tab bar controller
        // if user is not logged in  => show onboarding controller
        
        if isUserLoggedIn {
            Presentermanager.shared.show(vc: .mainTabBarController)
        } else {
            Presentermanager.shared.show(vc: .loginViewController)    
        }
        
    }
}
```

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import MBProgressHUD

//protocol LoginDelegate: class {
//    func showMainTabBarController()
//}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let isSuccessfulLogin = true
    weak var delegate: LoginDelegate?
        
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordConfirmationTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var forgetPasswordButton: UIButton!
    
    private enum PageType {
        case login
        case signUp
    }
    
    private var errorMessage: String? {
        didSet {
            showErrorMessageIfNeeded(text: errorMessage)
        }
    }
    
    private var currentPageType: PageType = .login {
        didSet{
            setupViewFor(pageType: currentPageType)
            print(currentPageType)
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupViewFor(pageType: .login)
    }
    
    private func setupViewFor(pageType: PageType) {
        errorLabel.text = ""
        passwordConfirmationTextField.isHidden = pageType == .login
        signUpButton.isHidden = pageType == .login
        forgetPasswordButton.isHidden = pageType == .signUp
        loginButton.isHidden = pageType == .signUp
    }
    
    private func showErrorMessageIfNeeded(text: String?) {
        errorLabel.isHidden = text == nil
        errorLabel.text = text
    }
    
    @IBAction func forgetPasswordButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    @IBAction func segmentedControlChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl){
        currentPageType = sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? .login : .signUp
    }
    
    @IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func loginButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: view, animated: true)
        
        delay(durationInSeconds: 2.0) {
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: false)
            if self.isSuccessfulLogin == true {
                print("test")
                self.delegate?.showMainTabBarController()
                
            } else {
                self.errorMessage = "Your password is invalid. Please try again."
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func closeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Presentermanager.shared.show(vc: .mainTabBarController)
    }
    
}

extension LoginViewController: LoginDelegate {

    func showMainTabBarController() {
        Presentermanager.shared.show(vc: .mainTabBarController)
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.delegate?.showMainTabBarController()` that's the one causing issue? Well, if you debug, what can you see? I guess that `self.delegate` is `nil`, that's why the method isn't called. You need to set the delegate.

Comment: Yes, If I use  `self.delegate?.showMainTabBarController() `, then It doesn't work at all. I set the delegate like this `protocol LoginDelegate: class {
    func showMainTabBarController()
}`

Comment: That's not setting the delegate, that's defining what a delegate can do.  Somewhere, you need to make the variable point to an actual instance.  A bigger problem is that you seem to be trying to define `LoginViewController` as both the delegate and the object that uses the delegate.

Comment: What's `Presentermanager.shared.show(vc: .mainTabBarController)`? I guess that somewhere, there is either `LoginViewController()` or an instantiation from Storyboard/Xib, but that's where you need to set the delegate, where you can retrieve the instance. Right now, it's hidden, you can't set anything.

Comment: hmm..I thought that was setting the delegate. How sould I setting then? and I should delete define delegate in LoginViewController?

Comment: @Larme     Presentermanager.shared.show(vc: .mainTabBarController) is go to the mainTabBarController. That's what I want to do when login is success.

Comment: I understand what is does from its name. The issue is that we don't know what's the code behind it. You need to do somewhere: `let theLoginViewController = ...; theLogincViewController.delegate = theLoadingViewController`. It's like having a person on duty (which has the delegate method), but that person isn't there, it's not set, you don't know who it is, so the job won't be done.

Comment: @Larme I see, I didn't set delegate like you said. I think I should study more and check how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't answering your specific question but if you try it out in a playground, it may clarify the basic idea of what the necessary pieces are for delegation to work.

Specifically, note that the class that implements the protocol is not the class that calls the delegate method.

```
protocol SomeService {
    func thingToDo()  // Define what a delegate can do
}

class ServingClass: SomeService {  // Define a class that can be a delegate
    func thingToDo() {  // Implement what this class does when it is a delegate
        print("I can do this")
    }
}

class ClientClass {
    var delegate: SomeService?  // Create a variable that may (or may not) point to a delegate
    
    func action() {
        if let delegate = delegate {  // Check if the delegate is available
            delegate.thingToDo()  // Use the delegate
        } else {
            print("Delegate wasn't set")
        }
    }
}

func testDelegation() {
    let cc = ClientClass()
    cc.action()  // Result when delegate is not set
    
    cc.delegate = ServingClass()  // Create a delegate object
    cc.action()  // Result when delegate is set
}

testDelegation()
```

Comment: @Phillips Mills Thank you for your sample. I should try this out.